# Confusion with the Django permission system

Tags: django-permissions

Django comes with a simple permissions system. It provides a way to assign permissions to specific users and groups of users. Like this： 'app_lable.model_name'. It may be convenient for the django admin, but I think it will be use difficult when I use it to control what people can to do with it.

For example, If I want to control whether a certain user can post a comment or see some portion content of my site. I have to config a permission group to him, but why not just add a user property like can_post or can_view_certain_portion?  Its seems more intuitive.
So who can help me understand those things? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The reason to keep permissions in a separate model is to leverage groups.

So if you needed to change the permissions on many users at once you could simply update the permissions of the group they are assigned to.

Also since users can belong to more than one group you have more flexibility for customizating permissions per user.

Keep in mind vanilla django permissions are model based so if you need to limit changing only certain fields to different users you will need something more robust like django-guardian.